# Translating C preprocessor macro to a D template or mixin

Tags: c-preprocessor, d

I'm working on translating a C library to D and I was wondering what the best way to mimic the following C preprocessor macro in D is.

```c
#define LV2_ATOM_SEQUENCE_FOREACH(seq, iter) \
for (LV2_Atom_Event* (iter) = lv2_atom_sequence_begin(&(seq).body); \
    !lv2_atom_sequence_is_end(&(seq).body, (seq).atom.size, (iter)); \
    (iter) = lv2_atom_sequence_next(iter))
```

Is this even possible to mimic with template programming or mixins in D?

An example of how the macro is used is

```c
LV2_ATOM_SEQUENCE_FOREACH(self->control, event) {
    do stuff with 'event'
    ...
}
```

I've tried writing a template which does something similar but I havent had much luck.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: how flexible are you on changing the usage code? cuz my first thought is to make it a regular D foreach. You can write wrapper functions or object to make it an input range, so the usage code would look like `foreach(event; LV2_ATOM_SEQUENCE(self.control)) { /* use event */ }`. ... i think, i haven't tried, but i think it is doable

Comment: Another possibility is to make it a function that takes a delegate, so that usage would look something like `LV2_ATOM_SEQUENCE_FOREACH(self.control, (event) { /* use event here */ } );` but again, the syntax is pretty different at the usage point and it needs to link in the function, so not directly identical.

Comment: I wanted to try my best to keep the translated code as true to the original library as possible however the more I look at this macro, the more I feel it isnt feasible. I hadn't considered writing a function that would return an input range and use it in a foreach.  I will look into that as it sounds like a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think I like the foreach approach better, but using a delegate might be simpler to implement.  Keeping the usage code the same as the original isn't all that important since it's unlikely that this will be used in any other library. Thanks for these suggestions.

Comment: when you write something up, feel free to answer yourself too. or if you don't want to i can write up more details down there later tomorrow or something

Comment: I couldnt get the `foreach` approach to work.  It may be doable but it's above my understanding. I opted to basically just write out the for loop where I needed it to save development time since I'm only using it in one place right now.  I want to try the delegate approach though so I will give that a try sometime today and post my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I got it to work.

```
void LV2_ATOM_OBJECT_FOREACH(const (LV2_Atom_Object*) obj, void delegate(LV2_Atom_Property_Body* prop) iterDelegate) 
{
    for (LV2_Atom_Property_Body* iter = lv2_atom_object_begin(&obj.body);
        !lv2_atom_object_is_end(&obj.body, obj.atom.size, iter);
        iter = lv2_atom_object_next(iter))
    {
        iterDelegate(iter);
    }
}
```

Then where the function is used

```
LV2_ATOM_OBJECT_FOREACH(object, delegate(LV2_Atom_Property_Body* prop)
{
    ...use prop here...
});
```

I'm still not sure that this is completely correct.  The calling function is `extern(C)` If i try to make `LV2_ATOM_OBJECT_FOREACH` extern(C) as well I get the following error

`function dplug.lv2.atomutil.LV2_ATOM_OBJECT_FOREACH(const(LV2_Atom_Object*) obj, extern (C) void delegate(LV2_Atom_Property_Body* prop) iterDelegate) is not callable using argument types (const(LV2_Atom_Object*), void delegate(LV2_Atom_Property_Body* prop) nothrow @system)`

Thanks a lot to Adam for the suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Comment: There's no need to make that extern(C), the reason for the error (which the error message says, but it is buried) is if that function is extern(C), it tries to make the callback extern(C) as well, which isn't the case for typical inline delegates. So your code is fine the way it is.